# Xamarin.froms How to change Grid direction Right to left or replace between columns content

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

A Grid with two columns one row, I want progremmatically to replace between column 1 and 2.

I tried :

```
    grdMainGrid.Children.Remove(child1);
    grdMainGrid.Children.Remove(child2);
 grdMainGrid.Children.Add(child1, 0, 0);
 grdMainGrid.Children.Add(child2, 0, 0);
```

But this action remove all the children of child1 and child2.

Answer (score 0):

So eventually it was not removing the children. but the order to add the children to the Grid determine the image was covering over the rest of the children.